# Symfony Extend Authentication Timeout on Request

Tags: authentication, symfony, security

My thinking was that Symfony2 would extend the `ExpireAt` on each page request made during the authenticated session. So if the timeout was 100 seconds and you made a page request, the new `ExpireAt` would be `time() + 100`. This "use it or lose it" authentication functionality is similar to what you get on a banking website.

The default functionality seems to be when the session timeout is set to `100` in the `config.yml`, the user only has 100 seconds to do what they can.

I don't think this will be to hard to implement but where should it be done? My first guess is in the `isEqualTo` method. Once you can determine the user is authentic you can re-up their `expireAt`. Or does the cookie need to be modified?

Comment: What version of symfony are you using and what setting are you using to set the timeout?

Comment: Most current. SF 2.1.5-DEV. There's Session Lifetime in the `config.yml` and `ExpireAt` in the user Object. I've got Remember-Me so it never expires .. Extending Full-Auth is what I'm focused on. It might just be circumstantial that Full-Auth goes away when Session Timeout expires. I only have my Session Timeout set for 100.

Comment: Did you try the `cookie_lifetime` option? http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-cookie-lifetime

Comment: i think my primary issue is with the user-provider and user-class. The cookies and session limits come into play a little because they need to exist maintain session state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the `refreshUser` method of the `UserProvider` and the `isEqualTo` method of the `UserClass`.

The `isEqualTo` method tells the user provider whether to `refreshUser(UserInstance user)`.

- **Step1** : `isEqualTo() returns false;` (as your understanding grow, so can this logic. But essentially, this triggers `refreshUser()`.

In all the basic user provider examples, the `refreshUser` & `loadUserByUsername` are identical. The to do what I'm talking about, the `refreshUser()` needs to be a little different.

- **Step2** : modify `refreshUser(UserInterface $user)`. What's being passed into this method is the original userClass. So the refreshUser is responsible for syncing the `expiresAt` or `credentialsExpireAt`

I use this logic in my `refreshUser()` to either extend the expiration date OR set it to the original expiration date (which is expired):

```
    if( time() > $user->getCredentialsExpireAt() ){
        $refreshedUser->setCredentialsExpireAt( $user->getCredentialsExpireAt() );
    }
```